# problem installing .net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5

I was trying to install .net 3.5 on one of the servers but got an error saying

[09/15/10,15:30:24] WIC Installer: [2] Error code 1603 for this component means "Fatal error during installation."
[09/15/10,15:30:24] WIC Installer: [2] Setup Failed on component WIC Installer
[09/15/10,15:30:26] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates WIC Installer is not installed.

I have the following text in dd_WIC.txt

[dd_WIC.txt]
0.422: ================================================================================
0.422: 2010/09/16 12:47:27.546 (local)
0.422: c:\0a081a898eb3f7b6b978d9\update\update.exe (version 6.3.4.0)
0.438: Hotfix started with following command line: /quiet /norestart /log:c:\tmp\2\dd_WIC.txt 
0.469: In Function GetBuildType, line 1170, RegQueryValueEx failed with error 0x2
0.500:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll is Not Present
0.500: First Condition in Test.WindowsCodecsVer.Section Succeeded
0.500: Condition succeeded for section Test.WindowsCodecsVer.Section in Line 1 of PreRequisite 
0.500:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsCodecsExt.dll is Not Present
0.500: First Condition in Test.WindowsCodecsExtVer.Section Succeeded
0.500: Condition succeeded for section Test.WindowsCodecsExtVer.Section in Line 2 of PreRequisite 
0.500:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WMPhoto.dll is Not Present
0.500: First Condition in Test.WMPhotoVer.Section Succeeded
0.500: Condition succeeded for section Test.WMPhotoVer.Section in Line 3 of PreRequisite 
0.500:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll is Not Present
0.500: First Condition in Test.PhotoMetadataHandlerVer.Section Succeeded
0.500: Condition succeeded for section Test.PhotoMetadataHandlerVer.Section in Line 4 of PreRequisite 
6.063: InstallInfCatalogFile: Installing c:\0a081a898eb3f7b6b978d9\update\WIC.cat as *000000*.cat...
6.063: VerifyTargetFileSize: Unable to verify size as Source = NULL for file c:\windows_000000_.cat
6.078: InstallCatalogFile: VerifyCatalogFile failed for c:\windows_000000_.cat; error=0x800b0109.
6.078: InstallInfCatalogFile: Installation failed; error=0x00000002.
6.078: IsInfFileTrusted: ValidateSingleFileSignature Failed: STR_FAILED_INF_INTEGRITY
6.109: WIC Setup encountered an error:  Setup could not verify the integrity of the file Update.inf.  Make sure the Cryptographic service is running on this computer.
20.156: CleanupTrustedInfFile: GetFileAttributes for C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\oem13.cat failed: 0x2
20.156: Setup could not verify the integrity of the file Update.inf.  Make sure the Cryptographic service is running on this computer.
20.156: Update.exe extended error code = 0xf0da
20.156: Update.exe return code was masked to 0x643 for MSI custom action compliance.

Can anyone plz tell me whats wrong during the installation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to download and install the Windows Imaging Component (WIC) found here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e011506-6307-445b-b950-215def45ddd8&displaylang=en

What version of Windows are you installing .NET 3.5 on?

Comment: Actually, I have a client who is using this and he wont give access to his server so I could personally look into the problem.

Comment: Moreover, I have also got him to install WIC but the problem persists

Comment: Good luck, there's not much more I can tell you :)